# How to disassembly elf in Linux kernel mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, elf, disassembly

I want to open an elf file in Linux kernel mode. and find whether it contains "in" and "out" instruction.
How to do that? Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: You can put a hooks on execve when code is mapped and just scan the raw memory for particular instruction codes

Comment: Alex Hoppus, do you know an algorithm to scan binary file? X86 instruction lenth is variable. It is a little difficult to obtain opcode.

Comment: siyuan, You can perform part of work in userspace with objdump like utility. Another way is to write your own disassembler

Comment: What is your end goal?

Answer (score 1):

> How to do that?

```
objdump -d /lib/modules/`uname -r`/.../some-module.ko
```